# Disable HNAP on D-Link router

Tags: network, attacks, attack-prevention, hardware, hardening

I'm concerned that [Home Network Administration Protocol](http://www.cisco.com/web/partners/downloads/guest/hnap_protocol_whitepaper.pdf) (HNAP) is a [serious vulnerability](http://www.sourcesec.com/Lab/dlink_hnap_captcha.pdf) that exposes consumer network routers to remote management by malicious entities such as government organisations and hostile corporate actors.

My question is twofold:

1. Is it possible to disable HNAP on a D-Link ADSL router?
2. Would you recommend it or not (please give reasons)?

Comment: for question 1 see D-Link documentation. For 2, it depends entirely on your needs, network, risk apettite, threats etc